# how to change place of words in string(symmetric)

Tags: java, string

I want to change place of words in string.
it need to be symmetric changing.
Example myString= "This website is so nice"
i want it will be = "nice so is website this"

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

The following will do what you want:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer("This website is so nice");

        String reversed = "";

        while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
            reversed = st.nextToken() + " " + reversed;
        }

        System.out.println("reversed is :" + reversed);

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List myList = Arrays.asList(myString.split(" "));
Collections.reverse(myList);
String reversed = String.join(" ", myList);
```